# Add a javascript call to link

Tags: javascript

I have a link on my page with href="javascript:sayhello()",
is it possible to add this function to full url?
Somethink like: http://example.com/page.html+javascript:sayhello()

Comment: And what should that do? Load the link and then execute the JavaScript on the subsequent page?

Comment: Yes, load page and call the function

Comment: You can use [**this example code**](http://jsfiddle.net/0aqkk3j4/) to achieve that, **note it will not work in jsfiddle, you have to import it to your website**. After pasting that code in a `<script>` tag just enter your website like this "*http://www.example.com?func=doSomething*" to see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

The part of the URL before the `:` says how the rest of the URL should be interpreted. When it starts with `http:`, it means that the link should make a `GET` request to an HTTP server, and request the page whose path is named in the rest of the URL. No Javascript is interpreted as part of that.

When it starts with `javascript:`, it means that instead of downloading a page from a webserver, it should execute the rest of the URL as Javascript, similar to the element having an `onclick`.

You could, however, write Javascript that redirects to the page:

```
<a href="javascript:sayhello(); location.href='http://example.com/page.html';">
```